# Save image and scroll in interface builder?

Tags: iphone, ipad, interface-builder

How do I get Interface builder to save images on the screen, and add the ability to scroll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean by "save images on the screen"? If you want to display an image in a view, you can simply drag a `UIImageView` onto the view in Interface Builder and set the image to whatever image you want (see [Graphics and Drawing](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/GraphicsandDrawing/GraphicsandDrawing.html) for more information).

As for scrolling, if you're using standard controls like `UITableView` or `UITextView`, these already have scrolling built-in, so you don't need to worry about adding scrolling capabilities. If you're doing something custom, then you probably want to look into [`UIScrollView`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).